# How to downloading and uploading file on NAO programmatically

Tags: nao-robot

I want to download file `/recordings/cameras` from Robot nao to my computer .
how can I do that ? Give me an example ( script ) please .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Paramiko package for that.

```
import paramiko


NAO_IP = "put_nao_ip_here"
NAO_USERNAME = "put_nao_username_here"
NAO_PASSWORD = "put_nao_password_here"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(NAO_IP, username=NAO_USERNAME, password=NAO_PASSWORD)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
localpath = 'path to save the file locally with filename'
remotepath = '/recordings/cameras/<filename>'
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```